# Question on Rudin 2.5

Tags: real-analysis

In Rudin's exercise 2.5, he asks for a bounded set with exactly three limits point. The typical example I have seen is something like this: 
$$\left \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \right \} \cup \left\{ \frac{1}{n} + 1 : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left \{\frac{1}{n} + 2 : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$
The three limit points are $0$ (first set), $1$ (second set), and $3$ (third set).

That the limit point of the set $\frac{1}{n}$ is $0$ is rather obvious and I haven't much trouble justifying it. The same is true for scaling by some fixed number. My big question, however, is how we know that the limit points of the union of disjoint sets are the unions of the limit points. This seems obvious, but I haven't thought of a way to prove it rigorously. Am I correct that we require that the sets be disjoint in order for this to hold, or could there be some overlap?

A hint on how to prove this fact or even an indication that my thinking on this is on the right track would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any point $x$ other than $0,1,2$. We have to show that $x$ is not  a limit point of the union. You can verify that if $0<r<\min \{|x|, |x-1|,|x-2|\}$ then $(x-r, x+r)$ contains at most finitely many points of the union. Hence $x$ is not  a limit point.

If $A =A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ...\cup A_N$ then any limit point of $A$ is a limit point of one of the sets $A_i$. For this let $x$ be a limit point of $A$. Then there is a sequence $(x_i)$ of distinct points of $A$ converging to $x$. Clearly at least one of the sets $A_i$ must contain $x_i$ for infinitely many $i$. Hence  there is a sub sequence of $(x_n)$ lying in $A_i$ for that particular $i$ which makes $x$ a limit point of $A_i$.

Comment: I understand why, in this case, these are the only three limit points. I was wondering, though, whether this is the case generally for the limit points of a union of disjoint sets.

Comment: For a **finite** disjoint union of sets, yes, the limit points are precisely the union of the limits points of those sets. I can add a proof of this to my answer if you wish. @Matt.P

Comment: I would love to see one if it wouldn't be too much trouble. Even a sketch of one would be great. Thank you.

Comment: @Matt.P I have edited my answer.